# HQ Trivia Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Winning HQ Trivia requires the player to correctly answer 12 questions each consisting of 3 multiple choice answers.  What is the formula for determining the probability of randomly answering all 12 questions correctly, assuming a .33 probability of answering each question correctly?

Comment: $ {.33}^{12} $?

Answer (score 1):

We have a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ to answer each question correctly, so in total $p = \frac{1}{3^{12}}$